# Posting and processing data in html checkbox arrays

Tags: php, html

I would like to post data in checkboxes, as like

```
<?php foreach($data as $foreignid => $id): ?>
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="photoids[<?php echo $foreignid; ?>]" 
       value="<?php echo $id;?>"
                       />
```

If I go this way only one key-value pair remains in my `$_POST` array.

If I leave the `photoids[]` array empty, (not echoing out the `$foreignid`) all of the key-value pairs remains in `$_POST` array, but then i don't have access to the `$foreignid` variable which that I need in my code.

What is the best workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php foreach($data as $foreignid => $id): ?>
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="photoids_<?php echo $foreignid; ?>" 
       value="<?php echo $id;?>"
                   />
```

And then parse keys in `$_POST` array that begin with `photoids` to obtain foreignid.

Or use this:

```
<?php foreach($data as $foreignid => $id): ?>
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="photoids[]" 
       value="<?php echo $foreignid . '_' . $id;?>"
                   />
```

And then parse values to obtain foreignid and id.

Of course, assuming that underscore '_' will not show up in foreignid or id.

You can parse name or value using:

```
$src = '123_987';
$arr = explode('_', $src);
```

`$arr[0]` will contain 123 and `$arr[1]` will contain 987.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<?php foreach($data as $foreignid => $id): ?>
<input type="checkbox" 
name="photoids[<?php echo $foreignid; ?>]" 
value="<?php echo $foreignid."/".$id."/".$data;?>"
/>
```